# Poker.SE home game proposal

Tags: discussion

Who would like to play in a "Home Game"?

I tried to set one up when the site was in its infancy 8 years ago, but perhaps now would be better, given the circumstances.

If there is enough interest, gauged by comments, upvotes, answers etc., then I will set-up a Pokerstars "Home Game" for us to play in. @jeffrey-blake mentioned in that previous post that US players will sadly not be able to join due to the restrictions on Pokerstars, but if there is an equivalent feature or setup capable on another site, let's do it there.

We can promote the game using a [Community Promotion Ad](https://poker.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308/community-promotion-ads-2020). It could be a regular thing, once every week or two for a tournament; cash games available all the time.

If you want to find out more, visit https://www.pokerstars.uk/poker/home-games/